# Prettier breaks the import statement into two lines

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

I am trying to prevent prettier from breaking my code. Current setup causes an import statement that is 125 characters long to break into 2 lines which results in an error.

```
import DiagnosticsResponseMessageContainer from 'components/DiagnosticsResponseMessage/DiagnosticsResponseMessageContainer';
```

The import line looks like this after save, and I get red squeaky lines under from saying that I need `{` to fix it:

```
import DiagnosticsResponseMessageContainer, 
from 'components/DiagnosticsResponseMessage/DiagnosticsResponseMessageContainer';
```

- Tried changing `printWidth` value to 250, 1000, and 5000 but it didn't affect the behaviour.
- Checked if I'm using any other similar tools such as Beautify, but I'm not.
- Added the recommended package `tslint-config-prettier` to make sure tslint/prettier working together not causing this issue
- Tried adding // prettier-ignore before the import line. Didn't change anything

This is the output of prettier after save:

```
["INFO" - 11:25:39 AM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 11:25:39 AM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "***",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "printWidth": 250,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "quoteProps": "preserve"
}
["INFO" - 11:25:39 AM] Formatting completed in 0.091ms.
```

What might be the problem here?